# How to create a lossless WebP image using toDataURL?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, webp

I'm trying out the WebP image format in Chrome using the canvas element. On MDN I saw that `toDataURL` accepts a second argument representing the quality of the resulting image.

I'd like to generate a lossless WebP image of a canvas element. However, if I pass `1` for quality (meaning 100%), I don't get the exact same pixels back. It looks like it is generating a lossy image.

Here's a test case: http://jsfiddle.net/Nf5ve/1/. When drawing the PNG image, a certain color of a certain pixel has a value of 40. After drawing a 100% quality WebP image of the canvas on itself, the same value has changed to 37. This does not seem lossless to me, even though I passed a quality of 100%.

Is it possible to have `toDataURL` create a lossless WebP image, and if so how?

Comment: Just to double-check, is there any transparency in the original PNG?

Comment: @Jacob Foshee: No, it's a random photograph from http://lorempixel.com.

Answer (score 5):

There are no official MIME types for webp so take this with a grain of salt for now.

Using "image/webp" on chrome in `toDataURL` will always result in a lossy webp image right now, even at quality "1"

There is seemingly no way to get a lossless webP image at this time

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance - but `image/webp-lossless` gives me a data URL starting with `data:image/png`. The same happens with any random MIME type - it falls back on png I think. I found [this message](https://groups.google.com/a/webmproject.org/d/msg/webp-discuss/wCIn7ZZdzVk/XNq6ifpeucoJ) though, stating that lossless is not stable just yet and should be released very soon. I guess I'll wait some time and see what happens.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking [this piece of the Chromium source](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/skia/ImageBufferSkia.cpp&exact_package=chromium&type=cs&l=332) confirms my theory. I'll update when I notice something interesting with regard to lossless WebP. Thanks for your help!

Comment: oh crap you're right, I should have been more diligent! I guess for now you're out of luck. There is no offical MIMEs for webp yet as far as the non-google world is concerned

Answer (score 0):

I tested and confirmed `image/webp-lossless` works as intended in Chrome these days. Just use it instead of `image/webp`

[The issue appears to have been resolved in 2016.](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40960200)

The image I used to test would have incorrect colors with lossy webp, and the colors are now correct.

To be certain it's truly a `webp` and not a `png` I used the following on Linux, where the filename is `webptest`

```
❯ file webptest
webptest: RIFF (little-endian) data, Web/P image
```

**Edit:** Hmmmm... but the returned value from `toDataURL` is `image/png` so now I haven't a clue what to think. But the size of the file is identical to one I created from Sharp which is certainly `webp`...